# How to implement "If image clicked then textContent change to X."

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a function that would do "if image is clicked then textContent changes to X". I already have a function that changes the title depending on the dataset of the image clicked but trying to integrate the two functions did not work out. I do not know how to put the aforementioned into code.

```
<div class="main-textbox-about-description">
                    <h1 class="main-textbox-about-description-text">St. Paul, Apostle of Christ</h1>
                </div>
                <!------------------------------------>
                <div class="main-textbox-about">
                    <div class="main-textbox-about-saints">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-peter-2176658_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-1" data-caption="St. Peter" onclick="Saintdesc();">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/saint-stylianos-2191792_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-2" data-caption=" St. Stylianos of Paphlagonia" onclick="Saintdesc();">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-demetrius-2176682_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-3" data-caption="St. Demetrius" onclick="Saintdesc();">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/archon-2086750_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-4" data-caption="Arch Angel Michael" onclick="Saintdesc();">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-andrew-2176673_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-5" data-caption="St. Andrew" onclick="Saintdesc();">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/saint-john-the-baptist-1652345_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-6" data-caption="St. John The Baptist" onclick="Saintdesc();">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-paul-2176669_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-7" data-caption="St. Paul, Apostle of Christ" onclick="Saintdesc();">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!------------------------------------>
                <div class="main-textbox-about-description-long">
                    <h1 class="main-textbox-about-description-long-text">St John the baptist</h1>
                </div>
```

```
const mainText = document.querySelector("h1.main-textbox-about-description-text");
const secondaryText = document.querySelector("h1.main-textbox-about-description-text-long")
const imgContainer = document.querySelector('.main-textbox-about-saints');

imgContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {


  mainText.textContent = e.target.dataset.caption;

});


function Saintdesc() {
  const Peter = document.querySelector(".main-textbox-about-saints-photos-1");
  const Stylianos = document.querySelector(".main-textbox-about-saints-photos-2");
  const Demetrius = document.querySelector(".main-textbox-about-saints-photos-3");
  const Michael = document.querySelector(".main-textbox-about-saints-photos-4");
  const Andrew = document.querySelector(".main-textbox-about-saints-photos-5");
  const John = document.querySelector(".main-textbox-about-saints-photos-6");
  const Paul = document.querySelector(".main-textbox-about-saints-photos-7");

    if (Paul === 'clicked') {
      secondaryText.textContent = "St. Pual was an apostle of Christ."
    }


}
```

Comment: I assume this is an exercise. I would recommend you to do it the same way as for the title. Remove your `Saintdesc`method and the `onclick`attribute. Add a `data-description` attribute to the images and then set the description within the already existing event listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple terms, you can use a small function to do this:

```js
var Desc = {
  "St. Peter": "Desc for St. Peter",
  " St. Stylianos of Paphlagonia": "Desc for  St. Stylianos of Paphlagonia",
  "St. Demetrius": "Desc for St. Demetrius",
  "Arch Angel Michael": "Desc for Arch Angel Michael",
  "St. Andrew": "Desc for St. Andrew",
  "St. John The Baptist": "Desc for St. John The Baptist",
  "St. Paul, Apostle of Christ": "Desc for St. Paul, Apostle of Christ"
};

function Saintdesc(text) {
  var el1 = document.querySelector(".main-textbox-about-description-text");
  var el2 = document.querySelector(".main-textbox-about-description-long-text");
  el1.textContent = text;
  el2.textContent = Desc[text];
}
```

```html
<div class="main-textbox-about-description">
  <h1 class="main-textbox-about-description-text">
    St. Paul, Apostle of Christ
  </h1>
</div>
<!------------------------------------>
<div class="main-textbox-about">
  <div class="main-textbox-about-saints">
    <img
      src="images/Saint Slide/st-peter-2176658_1280.jpg"
      class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-1"
      onclick="Saintdesc('St. Peter');"
    />
    <img
      src="images/Saint Slide/saint-stylianos-2191792_1280.jpg"
      class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-2"
      onclick="Saintdesc(' St. Stylianos of Paphlagonia');"
    />
    <img
      src="images/Saint Slide/st-demetrius-2176682_1280.jpg"
      class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-3"
      onclick="Saintdesc('St. Demetrius');"
    />
    <img
      src="images/Saint Slide/archon-2086750_1280.jpg"
      class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-4"
      onclick="Saintdesc('Arch Angel Michael');"
    />
    <img
      src="images/Saint Slide/st-andrew-2176673_1280.jpg"
      class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-5"
      onclick="Saintdesc('St. Andrew');"
    />
    <img
      src="images/Saint Slide/saint-john-the-baptist-1652345_1280.jpg"
      class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-6"
      onclick="Saintdesc('St. John The Baptist');"
    />
    <img
      src="images/Saint Slide/st-paul-2176669_1280.jpg"
      class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-7"
      onclick="Saintdesc('St. Paul, Apostle of Christ');"
    />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main-textbox-about-description-long">
  <h1 class="main-textbox-about-description-long-text">St John the baptist</h1>
</div>
```

I created a function that gets the param and sets the heading. Also, based on a param, it gets the long desc from an object and sets it.